# Set theory proof explanation (union of sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am practicing for my exam tomorrow and I stumbled upon an exercise I cannot solve

Prove that: 
$\cup A_i \times \cup B_j = \cup(A_i \times B_j)$
$i \in I$, $j \in J$,$(I,j) \in I\times J$

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Show that any element of the LHS is in the RHS, and conversely.  Post what you have done for a start and explain where you are stuck, then someone may be able to help you get a bit further.  You will need to correct the typos in the question first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glossing over trivialities by assuming $\left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j \right)$ is non-empty, here is one direction of the double containment argument:

Suppose $(x,y) \in \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \right) \times \left( \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j \right)$. By the [definition of cartesian product](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Cartesian_Product) we have $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ and $y \in \bigcup_{j \in J} B_j$. By the [definition of set union](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Set_Union) we know there is $k \in I$ so that $x \in A_k$. Likewise there is $l \in J$ so that $y \in B_l$. And so we have $(x,y) \in A_k \times B_l$ with $(k,l) \in I \times J$. Therefore $(x,y) \in \bigcup_{(i,j) \in I \times J} \left( A_i \times B_j \right)$.

---

It might be helpful to notice that the two hyperlinked definitions are fairly important here.